# Find elements of $\{0,1\}^4$

Tags: summation, vectors, uniform-distribution, multisets

For a classroom repartition problem, I need to find a multiset of 8 vectors among $\{0,1\}^4$ such that

1. Multiset: A vector can be present several times in the multiset
2. Their sum with the regular addition is $[4, 4, 4, 4]$
3. If a vector is in the multiset, its complementary is not in the multiset
4. (optional) We want to minimize the uniformity, defined by the squared sum of all (cross-products with the XOR operation, minus 2).
   For example the uniformity of the multiset $\{[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]\}$ is $0$, whereas the uniformity of the multiset $\{[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]\}$ is 4 and the uniformity of the multiset $\{[1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]\}$ is 4

I just can't even find a solution for the basis case 1. and 2.
If 2. is not possible, I want a proof and minimize how many of these vectors/complementary we need.

For example, here is a solution but the problem is that there are two complementary vectors [0, 1, 1, 1] and [1, 0, 0, 0]

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: [1111], [1111] , [1100], [1010], [0100], [0010], [0001], [0001] satisfies (2) and (3), I think. But I don't know what (4) means .

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: (4) means that (among other) we want the greater number of distinct coordinates, and in case of ex aequo, those where most distances between elements are 2, meaning half of the coordinates are different.

Comment: [0111], [1111] , [1100], [1010], [0100], [0010], [0001], [1001] is an even better solution, for example, because no two vectors are equal.

Comment: Transform your comment as an answer, add my optimization and let's call that the official answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what (4) means, but to satisfy (2) and (3):

[1111],
[1111],
[1100],
[1010],
[0100],
[0010],
[0001],
[0001]

Comment: [0111], [1111] , [1100], [1010], [0100], [0010], [0001], [1001] is an even better solution, for example, because no two vectors are equal

Comment: So you don't need a multi-set after all 